# Is there a way to use the Delphi debugger in a different editor?

Tags: delphi, debugging

I'm trying to get rid of the editor which is being shipped with the Delphi IDE as much as possible. Now I'm looking for a way to plug Delphi's debugger into a different editor.

Is there a hidden API, command line interface or similar that enables other applications to set debugger instructions (like setting breakpoints, step by step execution, evaluating variables etc)?

Comment: You're better off taking the Delphi IDE and stripping it down.

Comment: You could switch to FreePascal and use GDB.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid of editor from IDE? It is better then anything else for Pascal, you can't find something comparable.

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn In my opinion the Delphi IDE is slow, unstable and misses a lot of basic features. I'm working on a solution that fits my needs. I'm able to have code highlighting, basic language support including code completion and of course the ability to compile and run my code from a different editor. The only thing I'm missing is the ability to use Delphi's debugger. But I'm sure with the pass of the time I'm going to find a solution.

Comment: @KenWhite FreePascal is not alwys an alternative as I'm not always responsible to make technology decisions. And sadly there are some old projects which aren't easily portable to FPC ant the customer doesn't want to spend time and money in porting them.

Comment: If Delphi is a requirement, and you need to debug code, then use the IDE's debugger. It makes no sense to me to say *I must use Delphi because whoever makes those decisions says so, but I want to not use the tools designed specifically for the code I write in that language. Please show me a complex mechanism so I can spend a lot of time and effort working to avoid using them instead of doing real, productive work. Delphi's  IDE misses a lot of basic features. Mine compiles code and provide "basic language support including code completion".* Delphi's  does far more than that and debugs.

Comment: @KenWhite Delphi tends to crash in huge projects especially when there is much use of generics and there are many projects in a group which need to be compiled all at once while coding. Embarcadero knows about this fact for years without giving any solution. After around 10 years struggling with that unstable IDE I started to do my best to get rid of it. I'm much more productive when I write code in a different editor and use the IDE only for debugging and form design purpose. I can fix many bugs by just taking a look at my unit test results via command line. But I can't fix all bugs this way.

Comment: Have you considered writing a design-time package for the IDE that accesses OTA services and allows your editor to send it commands to open & compile your project, etc?

Comment: @MartynA Thanks for the idea! I was already thinking about it. And maybe I'm going to do it. But I don't like the idea that debugging is actually done inside the Delphi IDE. That means the IDE needs always to be active and mirrors all debugger events to its listeners.
I came also to different idea: Maybe I can use Delphi's RemoteDebugger. I _simply_ need to workout the TCP communication between IDE and RemoteDebugger in order to build my own client that I can later attach to my favorite editor. I don't know whether this is possible or not. But at least I'll try.

Comment: @Ken Debugging 64 bit code is something of a nightmare. Also debugging when the system is configured to use top down memory allocation fails. There's nothing better than the delphi debugger. It's a shame it's not more stable.

Answer (score 4):

The debugger is built in to Delphi's IDE, there are no APIs to access it externally.  However, within the IDE, there are ToolsAPI interfaces to allow IDE add-ons to perform some basic actions, like set/access breakpoints, attach the debugger to new/existing processes, evaluate expressions, etc.  But not step through running instructions AFAIK.